# The Connected Services component Office 365 APIs failed: (HRESULT 0x80004003)

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, office365, office365api

I've installed VS 2015 with Update 1 enterprise - twice now and getting the following error when I try and add an Office 365 connected service to my project.

The Connected Services component Office 365 APIs failed: (HRESULT 0x80004003).
Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Just before the error the following message appears in the output window:
Successfully authenticated against mydevtenant.onmicrosoft.com as mydevaccount@mydevtenant.onmicrosoft.com.

Have other people being able to get this to work with VS 2015 Update 1?
Any idea on how to debug the problem?

Thanks

Donal

Comment: Ok so added a different MVC project to the solution / configured azure / add connected service all pointing at same tenants and it worked. Went back in to problem project tried adding the connect service again and it worked!!!!

Comment: Didn't work for me unfortunately.